# Displaying an HD image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have recently started to learn android application development. Now I have some troubles in the image insertion. When i use the default images (launcher_background) my application seems to work fine. But any time I try to insert a HD image the application seems to stop. This has been going on for quite a while now.

Comment: `... the application seems to stop...` or **does** it?

Comment: most likely running out of memory when loading large images...
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Mybe it's because  your  image size is too big if your image is too big you should change image width and height to size of the image view or device display

There are thred party libaries you can use like :

https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer

For more information see the links below :

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-large-bitmaps-efficiently-in-android-66826cd4ad53